# Aqua Script for resizing image is not working wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-theming, thumbnails

I am developing a theme and i am using Aqua resizing script for the resizing the images in the theme, because most of my needs get fulfilled via this script . It is working fine in my local host but it is not working fine on my staging server. When i echo the images it says,

```
Boolean (False)

<?php
$thumb1 = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$img_url1 = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb1,'full' ); //get full URL to image (use "large" or "medium" if the images too big)
$image1 = aq_resize( $img_url1, 337, 182, true); //resize & crop the image
                  ?>
<pre><?php var_dump($image1); ?></pre>
<?php if($image1): ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image1; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: do you have read/write access on stage server?

Comment: yes i do have the access to all files 777